# The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor: Transform File to a List of File type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert an object of File type into a List in flutter but getting the said error.
I need to create a List of images(currently takes in a single image only)and save it to the tempPath & ImageName defined in the first 2 lines. I attempted the following :

```
#Initial declaration:
final tempPath = await _getTempPath();
String ImageName = '$ImageUuid.jpg';

#For Single Image   
File Image = File('$tempPath/$ImageName');

#For multiple images which is giving the error.
List<File>Images = List<File>('$tempPath/$ImageName')
```

My attempt is wrong but I cant figure how to transform

> File Image = File('$tempPath/$ImageName');
>
> to a List type.

Comment: `[File(path), File(otherPath)]`